# Trigger QuickFixCmdPost just with one function

Tags: vim

Consider the following minimal vimrc:

```
set nocompatible

function! OpenBuffer()
    execute "silent botright 2new empty_buffer"
    call append(line('$'), "This should only show up when running GrepFixme()")
    normal dd
endfunction

function! GrepTodo()
    execute "vimgrep/TODO/j %"
endfunction

function! GrepFixme()
    execute "vimgrep/FIXME/j %"
endfunction

augroup test_au
    au!
    au QuickFixCmdPost vimgrep call OpenBuffer()
augroup END

" TODO: foo
" FIXME: bar
```

As it can be seen in the GIF, the `QuickFixCmdPost` autocommand is triggered
when I call either the `GrepFixme()` or the `GrepTodo()` function. I want to
trigger the `QuickFixCmdPost` autocommand only when I call the `GrepFixme()`
function and not when I call the `GrepTodo()` function.  Is there a way a to
achieve that?

[image]

Comment: This smells like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the end goal you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @PeterRincker I actually have a function that runs `make` on a python file (and therefore opens the quickfix if there are errors) but I also have another function that runs `flake8` on the code every time I save a python file (and also opens the quickfix if there are errors). I finally have a third function that shows the python output in a preview window and it is called with `au QuickFixCmdPost cgetfile`. The problem is that when I save the file (and therefore run the flake8 function) the `QuickFixCmdPost` autocommand to show the python output is fired (and a new preview window opens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent autocmd from firing by using `:noautocmd` or setting `'eventignore'`. Example:

```
:noautocmd vimgrep/foo/
```

For more help see:

```
:h :noa
:h 'eventingore'
```